# TypeError: video is null - what is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I have a video on my page, which is loaded async ..

```
<video controls="" id="galMainVideo" class="galMainVideo" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <source src="https://examplde.com/video/10.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

no I try to pause/stop it but when I do

```
var vid = document.getElementById("#galMainVideo");
vid.get(0).pause();
```

I get a error **TypeError: vid is null**

what is it? what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

It means there is no element inside vid. There isn't any id = "#galMainVideo".
So remove the "#".

```
var vid = document.getElementById("galMainVideo");
```

In jQuery works:

```
   var vid = $("#galMainVideo");
```